# AS3 | FPS issue while running on browser

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, frame-rate

I've built a small game that running perfectly while on local (from Flash). It's a small 60-fps game. Using the same computer, I'm playing the swf using a browser (Chrome, Firefox, Explorer) however it's running extremely slow. I'm using swf monitor (and Browser monitor) there you can see clearly the swf is running with 61/60 fps however this is just not true. Seem like the browser is forcing swf fps down to around the 20 fps or so. I've also tried Wmode (direct / GPU) but nothing. What is going on?

Comment: Too little information (no code, no demo, no explanation of used libraries etc.). As the question stands now, people can only guess what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try adding some more information. Guess I was wondering if this is a common issue or it's just me.

Comment: You could have answered yourself 'or it's just me' : if it was everybody, people would have dropped Flash 15 years ago.Try different browser, if it's the same your game is too CPU intensive and needs to be optimized.

Comment: I'm still investigating it, while my second computer is strong as hell that's why I cannot trust it (yes, it's run fast). However I assume that because I have no graphic card on this computer (just a built-in) the browser render my swf really slow, and somehow while running it locally Flash can handle it smoothly even without a graphic card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating my graphic card drivers, everything works perfectly even on Browser. Flash can handle it perfectly without updated drivers, but on a browser it's a must to have, else it will damage application performance and FPS.